# Update configuration file vb.net programmatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, config

I have created a form that shows a number of settings held in the exe.config file, that I would like the user to be able change. For example I have a text box named `txtReadServer` that I populate with the setting `ReadServer` in the following manner:
    `m_ConfigurationForm.txtReadServer.Text = My.Settings.ReadServer`

From what I have read on this and other forums, I need to use `ConfigurationManager` in order to update these setting in the exe.config at runtime. My problem is that when I try anything like the following: `Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)` Visual Studio seems to not know what the `Configuration` object is. I have tried add an `Imports System.Configuration` at the top of my class, but the word Configuration is still highlighted in the dreaded red!

Any help - or suggestions on the best way to allow users to configure an app would be gratefully received.

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: If you're allowing the user to change the settings, it should probably be a user setting, and not an application setting.  I've been where you are now.  You want to save yourself a lot of pain and re-think the scope of the settings.  If a user can change them, then they're user settings.

Comment: Thank you - I had not realised that Application vs User made a difference to read/write ease! Having changed the scope of all my settings, I can now simply assign the new text box: as follows `My.Settings.ReadServer = m_ConfigurationForm.txtReadServer.Text` and then save these using: `My.Settings.Save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference in your project to System.Configuration.

Comment: This does indeed answer the question. Wesley Long's comment on my question, that I look at changing the scope of my settings from Application to User is a more practical solution in my case. However for those looking to edit the config file, I found the following tutorial very useful: [link](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/working-with-configuration-files-and-visual-basic.htm)